# How to store response of url in a variable batch scripting

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to store the response of a URL into a variable in a batch script

Example:

```
set initial=PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')"
```

I'm trying to store the response of:

```
PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')"
```

into variable:

`initial`

But this is not working. How can I accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for /f`. Something like this.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')"`) do set initial=%%a
```

Comment: This seems to just download a file called `'(powershell` with it's content being the command itself

Comment: Make sure to use the backtick around the command. On my keyboard, it's the key above TAB.

Comment: Yes, I am, I copied and pasted your solution.

Comment: <BACK_TICK> `PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')"` </BACK_TICK>

Comment: OK, I guess it depends on what the contents of the URL are. Some characters will be interpreted differently in Batch, especially `<`, `|`, `>`,`&`. Also, `SET` has a limitation in that it only works for one line of text. If that's an issue, maybe you should pipe the output to a temporary file instead? Can you clarify what the contents of the URL are?

Comment: The content of the URL is plain text. literally its just a text "25"

Comment: If I do just do `PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://some-url/id')` in cmd, I get the response 25, however I want to store the response into a variable, hence my original question

Comment: Hmm. The line works for me. It's also the same as Hackoo's answer. I don't think it's an execution policy problem. I'm not sure why you have a different result. `For /f` will parse the output of the command and set it to the the variable. I've tried it, and it works for `http://myexternalip.com/raw` and a local test.html.

Comment: Yea it seems like it should work. I just executed that line `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://myexternalip.com/raw')"`) do set initial=%%a` and the response I got back was `%%a was unexpected at this time`

Comment: You must have run it in the cmd window directly. Use %a in cmd, but %%a in a batch file. Don't forget to change both places.

Comment: yep, that worked for me. However my problem still remains

Comment: What happens if you run this? You should get `Hello` as output. `for /f "usebackq delims=" %a in (``powershell -Command "Write-Output Hello"``) do @echo %a` You can follow that up with `@set initial=%a` instead of `echo` and see what you get. Just use one ``` inside the parentheses. I couldn't figure out how to escape the backtick in the comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126298/discussion-between-soja-and-arabian-albert).

Answer (score 1):

This an example showing you how to get your public ip address :

```
@echo off
set "URL=http://myexternalip.com/raw"
Call :GetResponse %URL%
echo %initial% 
Pause>nul & exit
::*****************************************************************
:GetResponse <URL>
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('%1')"`) do set "initial=%%a"
Exit /b
::*****************************************************************
```